# git branch -a ничего не показывает

Tags: git, branch

```
git branch -a
```

Команда ничего не показывает. Версия git 2.2
`git branch` с другими ключами тоже ничего не показывает.

Как я делал.

1. Создал папку
2. git init
3. скачал .gitignore
4. git remote add имяУдалРеп путьКудаленному_репозиторию
5. git remote -v #показывает путь к удаленной ветке

Что случилось с локальными ветками? Почему их нет?

Comment: так вы ни одной локальной ветки не создали. вот их и нет. а удалённых веток (если они вообще есть) не видите потому, что их ещё не скачивали.

Comment: Кстати в п4 у вас не имяВетки, а имя удалённого репозитория (обычно это origin)

Comment: aleksandr barakin, как их скачать? Нужно создать для них локальные ветки? Или сразу git pull?

Comment: Можно `git fetch`. Непонятно только, если у вас уже есть удалённый репозиторий, то зачем делать такие сложные телодвижения. Проще сразу склонировать (`git clone ...`)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался уже немного. А то я уже запаниковал, где же ветки, где master.. куда всё пропало.

1. Нужно сделать commit, `git commit -m "первый коммит"`
2. Затем создать ветку, чтобы она была.  `git branch имя_локальной_ветки`
3. Переключиться на ветку `git checkout имя_локальной_ветки`

Теперь можно будет с этой веткой работать. Подключить удаленный репозитория и отправлять наработки.

Comment: Вам в комментариях правильно рассказали, а этот ответ не очень правильный (история изменений будет не та, которую ожидают).

Comment: 0andriy, "которую ожидают".
 Ожидает кто? Какую ожидают?

Comment: Ожидают как минимум отсутствия "первый коммит" и совпадения хэш-сумм оригинальных коммитов.

Answer (score 0):

локальных указателей (мы же помним, что в программе *git* «ветка/branch» — это плавающий указатель на коммит, да?) программа *git* не показывает потому, что нет коммитов, на которые можно было бы указывать. создайте хоть один коммит и указатель `master` (в новомодном варианте — `main`) сразу же появится как чёрт из табакерки (и будет указывать на этот созданный коммит).

и «удалённых» указателей программа *git* не показывает ровно по той же причине — указывать не на что: вы же не забрали сами коммиты из подключенного вами «удалённого» репозитория. выполните команду `fetch` — и они появятся. и коммиты и указатели.

---

но вообще ваши действия выглядят несколько странно. вместо всего, о чём вы написали в вопросе, судя по всему, вам надо было всего лишь выполнить команду `clone` (если каталог не существовал, то он будет создан):

```
$ git clone путь/к/удалённому/репозиторию путь/к/пустому/каталогу
```

и скачать в этот (уже наполненный файлами, распакованными из хранилища) каталог файл `.gitignore`.